# Using Fuel in Kotlin with GET works but POST doesn't

Tags: post, kotlin, fuel

I am using Fuel to do a server call in Kotlin but, while the GET version works, the POST doesn't seem to pass anything to the server.

I based my code on a nice [Fuel Kotlin tutorial by Mushtaq](http://www.androidmads.info/2018/01/kotlin-http-example-using-fuel-http.html):

```
    val parameters = listOf("something" to "100")
    fun httpPostJson(view: View) {
    try {
        Fuel.post(PATH, parameters).responseJson { request, response, result ->
            tvPostResponse!!.text = result.get().content
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        tvPostResponse!!.text = e.message
    } finally {
        progress!!.dismiss()
    }
}
```

The server script is just a PHP file that does a var_dump() for $_REQUEST, $_GET, and $_POST.  It shows the expected values for Fuel.get() but they are all array(0) for the Fuel.post() call.  I've tried calling it from a regular webpage and it works as expected for both GET and POST so it seems like I'm missing something in the Kotlin code.  I have no idea what...maybe some simple setting?  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing it to below and see if you are observing any status code or 4xx status code or any error.

```
import com.github.kittinunf.result.Result as FuelResult

 val parameters = listOf("something" to "100")
    fun httpPostJson(view: View) {
    try {
        Fuel.post(PATH, parameters)
        .responseJson { request, response, result ->

                     var data
                     when (result) {
                        is FuelResult.Failure -> {
                          println( String(response.data)) // response.data  {"statusCode":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"invalid session"}
                          data =  String(response.data);
                         }

                        is FuelResult.Success -> {
                         data = result.get().content
                         println(data) // response.statusCode is also available if we need to go that route.
                }
            }
            tvPostResponse!!.text = data
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        tvPostResponse!!.text = e.message
    } finally {
        progress!!.dismiss()
    }
```

Also, there no body being passed in the post request in the post. Make sure contract is correct with the service.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but it just goes into the FuelResult.Success branch and prints out what the server returned (which is that it has array(0) for the $_REQUEST, $_GET, and $_POST arrays).  As for there being no body, I just need to pass the parameters to the server.  Also, the same code works with the GET.  Is that what you mean?  I'm testing it out on my own server so I'm thinking it should work but if you have any other ideas, I'm all ears--thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was that the server domain was in the form domain.com and the hosting provider automatically mapped it to www.domain.com, which affected the POST but not the GET.

Adding a "www" to the domain in the Kotlin code solved the problem. So, although the problem was technically in the Kotlin code, it was really on the server side.